# Array of Pointers dereferencing when accessed in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I have a array structure that should hold a pointer to another structure. My structures are like this:

```
struct Term{
    char* term;
    int times;
};
typedef struct Term TERM;

struct HeapTer{
    TERM* Term;
    size_t used;
    size_t size;
};
typedef struct HeapTer HEAPTER;

struct Pack{
    HEAPCON* hCon;
    HEAPTER* hTer;
};
typedef struct Pack PACK;
```

Pack will just hold the pointers of both arrays I will return from my structure loading function.

My problem is when I will call a function, where I will insert a given term to the consults term heap.

```
InsertHeapTer(pack->hTer->Term[ind_term],consult->hTer)
```

Where `InsertHeapTer` is defined as `InsertHeapTer(TERM* Ter, HEAPTER *t)`.
The compiler gives me the following error, `error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'TERM {aka struct Term}' from type 'TERM * {aka struct Term *}'`.

So, it is saying that when I use `pack->hTer->Term[ind_term]` it gives me a `TERM`and not a `TERM*`, even though it is defined as a pointer in the structure.
What am I doing wrong and why is this happening?

EDIT:
Code to reproduce:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct Termo{
    char* termo;
    int vezes;
};
typedef struct Termo TERMO;

struct HeapTer{
    TERMO* Termo;
    size_t usado;
    size_t tam;
};
typedef struct HeapTer HEAPTER;

struct consulta{
    char *Local;
    HEAPTER *hTer;
};
typedef struct consulta CONSULTA;

struct HeapCon{
    CONSULTA* con;
    size_t usado;
    size_t tam;
};
typedef struct HeapCon HEAPCON;

struct Pacote{
    HEAPCON* hCon;
    HEAPTER* hTer;
};
typedef struct Pacote PACOTE;

void InsereHeapTer(TERMO* Ter, HEAPTER *t){
}

int main(){
    PACOTE* pack;
    CONSULTA* consulta;
    int ind_termo=1;

    InsereHeapTer(pack->hTer->Termo[ind_termo],consulta->hTer);

    return 0;
}

void InsereHeapTer(TERMO* Ter, HEAPTER *t){
}
```

I'm sorry, but this was the minimal setup I could do.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal program that reproduces the issue you are facing?

Comment: What's a `TERMO`?  Is it just a typo for `TERM`, or is it another type?  That particular type happens to be central to the question.

Comment: @JohnBollinger It is a typo, I fixed that.

Comment: @jxh I added the consult definition there, with this you can easily generate a bit of code to reproduce it. If needed, I can provide a link to download my full test project (a bit different, but complete).

Comment: @RafaelKehl It is upon the question asker to provide a [MCVE] that exemplifies the problem.  If it would be easy for us to generate the code to reproduce it, it should be easy for you to provide it as it is for your benefit.  The fewer hoops we have to jump through, the more likely it is for you to receive help.

Comment: `HEAPCON` seems to be undefined still.

Comment: I provided a full code example to reproduce what is happening, despite the names being a bit different, this is how I could isolate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify the offending line of code, you can do:

```
TERMO* termo = pack->hTer->Termo;
InsereHeapTer(termo[ind_termo],consulta->hTer);
```

Clearly, `termo` is a `TERMO*`. The `[]` operator is defined like this:

> The definition of the subscript operator **`[]`** is that **`E1[E2]`** is identical to **`(*((E1)+(E2)))`**.
>   <sub>C.11 §6.5.2.1 ¶2</sub>

Thus, your function call is equivalent to:

```
InsereHeapTer(*(termo + ind_termo),consulta->hTer);
```

And this can be simplified again:

```
TERMO* termo_plus_ind = termo + ind_termo;
InsereHeapTer(*termo_plus_ind,consulta->hTer);
```

When you dereference a `TERMO*`, you get a `TERMO`.

Comment: The error the compiler is given is exactly that I defined in the struct a `TERMO*`, but it says that `pack->hTer->Termo[ind_termo]` is just a `TERMO`. The definition you gave doesn't seem correct, or I couldn't understand it.

Comment: If you have `int *x;` representing an array of integers, do you expect `x[i]` to be `int *` or `int`? I can tell you it will be an `int`.

Comment: Now I got it! Thank you a lot! I will do some tests here and I think just using the operator `&` may solve my issue without having to use a `TERMO **`.

Answer (score 3):

> So, it is saying that when I use `pack->hTer->Term[ind_term]` it gives
>   me a `TERM` and not a `TERM*`,

Yes.

> even though it is defined as a pointer in
>   the structure.

Be careful: even though *what* is defined as a pointer?  It is `pack->hTer->Term` that is so defined.  With that being the case, then, `pack->hTer->Term[ind_term]` indeed has type `TERM`.  It is equivalent to `*(pack->hTer->Term + ind_term)`.

And that suggests a resolution: if you meant to pass a pointer to that item instead of a copy of the item, then you can use pointer arithmetic to produce the wanted pointer as `pack->hTer->Term + ind_term`.  I tend to prefer the simplicity of that, but stylistically, I'm sure some people would prefer the equivalent expression `&pack->hTer->Term[ind_term]`.

Comment: This fixes the compilation problem, but what it gives is indeed the pointer to the given Term that I associated to it earlier?

Comment: I've no idea what you did earlier, @RafaelKehl.  The `Term` member is a pointer to a `TERM`, apparently the first of several contiguous ones.  If your function modifies one of the pointed-to `TERM`s then the modifications will be visible to the caller.  I cannot speak to design issues around whether this is how your program is supposed to work, since that  remains unclear.

Comment: In particular, @RafaelKehl, your title suggests that you think you have an array of pointers, but that's not what the `Term` member is.  If that's indeed what it's supposed to be then you need another `*` in its type.  But that will affect all code that touches it.

Comment: I'm trying to adapt a integer array to work with my structure. I must have an array with all `TERM`s and each `CONSULT` should have an array with some `TERM`s. I'm trying to use my `TERM` pointer that's already in the main array on the `CONSULT` array. Always keeping modifications on the caller.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying what is happening with the pointers. Maybe sending the array and the index should fix it?

Comment: @RafaelKehl, yes, sending the array and a separate index would be an alternative to what I already suggested in my answer: send `pack->hTer->Term + ind_term`, which is a pointer directly to the element.  You may find it more readable to use two separate arguments.